# Does the docusign base uri change for a specific user?

Tags: docusignapi

Does the docusign base uri change for a specific user? Can I fetch it just once in my application and use it for all subsequent docusign API calls? Also can we use same access token for multiple API calls until it expires after an hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base URIs may change when calling different *accounts*. All users on the same account will have the same base URI, but keep in mind that some users are members of multiple accounts.

In practice, yes, you can fetch the base URI once and use it for all subsequent API calls against the same account.

Yes, tokens generated through the JWT Grant workflow last for an hour and should be reused whenever possible. As a best practice, consider requesting a token at around 50 minutes into the hour so that you have a brief window of overlap to ensure a smooth transition.